# How to close the ends of a cylinder in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a 'closed' cylinder in matplotlib but I am not sure how to go about doing this. So far I have a cylinder with the ends open, the code for this is as follows:

```
#make a cylinder without the ends closed
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.linalg import norm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
import numpy as np
import math




fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')



origin = [0,0,0]
#radius = R
p0 = np.array(origin)
p1 = np.array([8, 8, 8])
origin = np.array(origin)
R = 4

#vector in direction of axis
v = p1 - p0
#find magnitude of vector
mag = norm(v)
#unit vector in direction of axis
v = v / mag
#make some vector not in the same direction as v
not_v = np.array([1, 0, 0])
if (v == not_v).all():
    not_v = np.array([0, 1, 0])
#make vector perpendicular to v
n1 = np.cross(v, not_v)
#normalize n1
n1 /= norm(n1)
#make unit vector perpendicular to v and n1
n2 = np.cross(v, n1)
#surface ranges over t from 0 to length of axis and 0 to 2*pi
t = np.linspace(0, mag, 600)
theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
#use meshgrid to make 2d arrays
t, theta = np.meshgrid(t, theta)
#generate coordinates for surface
X, Y, Z = [p0[i] + v[i] * t + R * np.sin(theta) * n1[i] + R * np.cos(theta) *    n2[i] for i in [0, 1, 2]]


#make the color for the faces
col1 = plt.cm.autumn(np.ones(600)) # linear gradient along the t-axis
col1 = np.repeat(col1[np.newaxis,:, :], 100, axis=0) # expand over the theta-axis



ax.plot_surface(X, Y,Z, facecolors = col1, shade = True,edgecolors = "None",    alpha = 0.4, linewidth = 0)

plt.show()
```

Running this code produces the following image[image]

How would I close the ends of the cylinder with a solid circle (i.e. disk)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and easy way that's similar to your other code is to generate a surface using strips from `r=0` to `r=R`.  Right before `plt.show()` add the following lines:

```
R = np.array([0,R])
# cap at t=0
X, Y, Z = [p0[i] + np.outer(R, np.sin(theta)) * n1[i] + np.outer(R, np.cos(theta))*n2[i] for i in [0, 1, 2]]
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, edgecolors = "r", alpha=.4, linewidth = .1)
# cap at t=mag
X, Y, Z = [p0[i] + v[i]*mag + np.outer(R, np.sin(theta)) * n1[i] + np.outer(R, np.cos(theta))*n2[i] for i in [0, 1, 2]]
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, edgecolors = "r", alpha=.4, linewidth = .1)
```

Here the colors are more for illustrative purposes, mostly so you can see the strips.  The result looks like:
[image]